# How to determine if first two elements of a value are integers or characters?

Tags: python, date

My goal is to save the number of a day, from a  date value, in a variable
For example:

```
    today_str = 10-2-2018
    date_num = 10
```

or

```
    today_str = 3/5/2018
    date_num = 3
```

In addition, I want to check if it's 2 integers or only 1 so I can save the day's number in a value.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `'10-2-2018'.split('-')[0]`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That doesn't work for the second string

Comment: Just a helpful hint that might lead towards one possible solution.

Comment: i tried lots of things but nothing really worked, had been strugling for half an hour.Finally found a solution ! Look:

Comment: if today_str[0:1] != "0":      
 day_numb = today_str[0:2]
else:
 day_numb = today_str[1:2]

Comment: if first number is 0 it means its a day between 1-9 , if its not 0 it means its a day between 10-31 , right ? I think it works properly.What do you think guys ?

Comment: @ΒαγγέληςΜανουσάκης See my answer below, both of those are more reliable than using your `if-statement`

Comment: Allright, i will test out all of them.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pure Python**

You could use `next()` on a generator expression to get the first index of a character which *is not a digit* then `slice` up to this index:

```
>>> date_str = '10-2-2018'
>>> date_str[:next(i for i, c in enumerate(date_str) if not c.isdigit())]
'10'
>>> date_str = '3/5/2018'
>>> date_str[:next(i for i, c in enumerate(date_str) if not c.isdigit())]
'3'
```

---

**Regex**

You can also use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> date_str = '10-2-2018'
>>> re.search('^[0-9]+', date_str).group(0)
'10'
>>> date_str = '3/5/2018'
>>> re.search('^[0-9]+', date_str).group(0)
'3'
```

---

I've also put this on [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/CZADPb/1) where you can see an explanation of how this works.

---

Comment: As i am new in Python , i havent been working with such things.Thanks for the info , i will definetly check it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
today_str = '10-2-2018'
date_num = ''

if '-' in today_str:
    date_num = today_str.split('-')[0]

elif '/' in today_str:
    date_num = today_str.split('/')[0]

else:
    raise Exception('Wrong date format')

length_date = len(date_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
"^[0-3]?[0-9]"
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `[0-3]?` matches a digit between `0` and `3`, zero or one time (because of `?`)
- `[0-9]` matches a digit between `0` and `9`

This regex will **find your day**, and also **make sure that it is valid**.

Using the regex with Python:

```
import re

today_str = "10-2-2018"
date_numb = re.match(r"^[0-3]?[0-9]", today_str).group(0)

today_str = "3/5/2018"
date_numb = re.match(r"^[0-3]?[0-9]", today_str).group(0)
```

Comment: i will search about regex library.Didn't know this even existed as i am new in pythonprogramming.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is a bad idea**. You *can* use `re`, `isdigit`, `split` or some other generic functions.

But for your use case there are ready-made tools that *add* structure to your data, rather than turn a date into an alphanumeric variable. Here is an example with `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd

today_str = '10-2-2018'

pd.to_datetime(today_str, dayfirst=True).day

# 10
```